# Adding new Spreadsheet using Google Drive API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I'm trying to add a new Spreadsheet to Google Drive, using the Google Drive Api.I don't know which feed to use to add the spreadsheet.
To add a new Worksheet to an existing Spreadsheet, my `WorksheetFeed` is:

```
 WorksheetFeed = spreadsheet.Worksheets;
```

So, to add a new Spreadsheet to Google Drive, which feed i was supposed to use? In the [sample](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_a_new_document_or_file_with_metadata_only), is used `DocumentsListQuery.documentsBaseUri`, but when I try to use that feed, I recieve the error: `Execution of request failed: https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with the http api:

- post url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files"
- post data must contain at least:
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
  'title': 'hello spreadsheet'
- response.data.id gives you the new spreadsheet id.

Note that currently this will create a regular (old) sheet, not the "new sheets" that Google released recently.